# Append timestamp to top command output

Tags: osx, awk, top

All,
I'm using

```
top -l 0 -s 1  -pid XXX -stats rsize | awk 'NR%13==0; fflush(stdout)' > output.txt
```

to store the rsize value of a process in a file. Currently the contents of output.txt look like this:

```
3828K+   
3832K+  
3836K+  
3840K+  
3840K   
3840K
```

I would like to modify this one-liner to include timestamp along with the value. 
How do I modify the awk part of the above one-liner and add timestamp to it? The resultant output should look like this:

```
1338936728 3828K+  
1338936729 3838K
```

I'm on a Mac OSX. I would like to make a timestamp Vs rsize plot.

Comment: Can you include a complete output line? I don't have an OSX machine, and my version of `top` doesn't take the same flags

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: What do you mean by "complete output line"? I'm essentially running the top command in batch mode in the above one-liner

Comment: A line unprocessed by `awk`. I assume "timestamp" is one of the other columns

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: There is no timestamp column in the top command output. I thought of modifying the awk part of the one-liner to add a timestamp

Comment: I am on a mac and that's not giving me anything remotely like your output.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your awk version (you probably have to use `gawk` instead of awk) or directly run date in your awk commandline, but

```
awk 'NR%13==0 { printf  "%d %s\n",  systime(), $0 ; fflush(stdout) }'
```

will print the current timestamp in front of the current line. For more information have a look at the [gawk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) about time functions.